# Exporting jar from eclipse won't work

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jar, executable-jar

I built a Java project in eclipse.  It runs fine from within eclipse.  I've exported it as a jar before and it's worked fine.  It's been a while since the last export, though.  This time, when I exported and clicked on the jar, nothing happened.

Running it from the command line reveals the following error:

```
C:\>java -jar "C:\Users\Quinn\Desktop\think.jar"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class think.Main with modifiers "public static"
```

What does this error mean? Are there any reasons why this could happen?  I haven't been able to find any mention of it online.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
when I unzip the jar, the contents looks like this:
[image]

the manifest (in META-INF) looks like this: (yes, it has an extra empty line)

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ substance-6.1.jar trident.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: think.Main
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Comment: I am confused as to how the eclipse class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader` is involved when you are running this from the command line. Do you have any idea how that is the case? Also, could you unzip your jar and show us the structure of the archive?

Comment: Eclipse JDK and system jdk is different i guess here . please check

Comment: Honestly, I am confused about that too.  I never specified to use anything in org.eclipse explicitly. I am working on unpacking the jar right now and will have that up soon

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is awkward.  It turns out that, although my main method was `public static`, the containing class was not public.  Everything is now fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

JarRsrcLoader is included in the Jar when you use Export > Runnable JAR file. It deals with nested jar files in the jar.

JarRsrcLoader is trying to find your `main` method of `think.Main` but can't find a method called `main` which is `public static`.